# as3: Making an animation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am playing with animation in AS3 and flex4, and I've come into a problem. My application is a game board (like a chess board), where each field is a border container added to some position.

Also I am adding a child element (shape), to this container on mouse click. What I want to achieve is to be able to move shapes smoothly from one field to another. But it appears that the shape goes behind the neighbor field this way http://screencast.com/t/iZ3DCdobs.

I believe this happens because shape is a child of specific border container, and to make it visible over every other container, I would need to use layers somehow....

I would be happy if anybody could suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right on that. You should add the movable objects to a different layer.
As there are no typical layers in AS, you could try to drop the fields in one sprite and any other objects to a different an than place them on each other, so that when you will move a object it won't go behind other objects.

If you place both sprites in the same position you will still have accurate x,y positions between movable objects and fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

First one is to have different layers for your DisplayObjects: as an example, the bottom layer would hold all the boards, and the upper layer would hold all the pieces.

Second option is to manipulate the index of the objects with [swapChildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29), [swapChildrenAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29), and [setChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29). So to bring a MovieClip to the topmost front, you would do `MovieClip(parent).setChildIndex(this, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is that always the shape object gets hidden behind the next ( right side ) grid container, the I suggest you create your grid in reverse.

Suppose you are creating a chess grid. that is a 8x8 grid. Normally you would create your grid using 2 for loops, looping from 0 to 8 with say the x and y points starting at 0,0 for the first grid and going on till the end. What I suggest you to do is to create from 8,8 to 0,0.

Display objects in flash are stacked on top of each other based on their child index.

For example:  If you create two objects. Rectangle and Circle as follows

```
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
this.addChild(rect);
var circ:Circle = new Circle();
this.addChild(circ);
```

The circle will always be on top of the rectangle in this scenario because the circle was added after the rectangle to the display list.
So if you reverse the order of creation of your grid, the right grid cell will be added to the display list first and so the grid cells to the left will always be on top of the right ones. Hence, the problem that you are facing will not occur.